# Adding id and custom attribute in fabric js

Tags: fabricjs

I am new to fabtric js. How can I add auto generating id and custom attribute to fabric js object.
For example, I would like to add an id that is autogenerated with increment integer of type of object and category: 'new' when an object is added

As far as I am concerned, fabric js does not support this by default.

```
var text = new fabric.IText('Enter text here', {
        id: 'text-i' -> where i increment according to number of IText in the canvas
        left: 150,
        top: 50,
        type: 'new'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

one way you can achive this is set some extra object in your canvas:

```
canvas.ObjectCounter = {};
```

then add all the tipes to it:

```
canvas.ObjectCounter.['text'] = 0;
canvas.ObjectCounter.['rect'] = 0;
canvas.ObjectCounter.['i-text'] = 0;
```

and so on...

when creating object:

```
var text = new fabric.IText('Enter text here', {
        id: 'text-' + canvas.objectCounter['i-text']++,
        left: 150,
        top: 50
});
```

be aware that 'type' is a property that needs to stay as it is, do not change it.

This will be just number of objects created if you handle like this.
If you want to know how many of them are on the canvas you have to use something different in the events

```
canvas.on('object:added', function(e){});
canvas.on('object:removed', function(e){});
```

Comment: I thought that we cannot simply add any custom attributes to fabric js directly other than those pre-defined?

Comment: you shoud do carefully to not overwrite any that is already defined, and do not expect those new attributes to work automatically with object saving and restoring